# On the existence of symmetric matrices with prescribed number of 1's on each row

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

We are considering the following problem:

Given an integer $n$ and a sequence of integers $r_i,\ 1\le i\le n$, with $0\le r_i\le n-1$ does there exists a symmetric matrix $A$ such that the diagonal elements of $A$ are $0$'s, the off-diagonal elements are only $-1$ and $1$ and for each $i$ there are exactly $r_i$ $1$'s on the $i$-th row of $A$? How do we construct such a matrix? How do we construct all such matrices (up to some equivalence relation).

For example, if $n$ is even and half of $r_i$ are equal to $n$, the other half to $n-1$. How do we construct such matrices? What about the case when $\{r_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a constant sequence? When such a matrix exists?

The problem is related to the existence of certain codes with given distances between the codewords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace each $-1$ with $0$. Then the matrix you look for is the adjacency matrix of a graph with a given degree sequence $r_1, r_2, \dots$. Reconstruction of such a graph (and its adjacency matrix) is known as the *graph realization* problem. E.g., see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_realization_problem) or [this webpage](https://piperfw.github.io/degreeSequences/) for additional details and solutions.

Comment: The linked proof of the correctness of the Havel-Hakimi algorithm also seems to imply that any two realizations can be obtained from each other by a sequence of replacements of the following form:
Pick 4 vertices $A,B,C,D$ so that there are edges $AB$ and $CD$, but no edges $AC$ and $BD$. Then replace the edges $AB$ and $CD$ by $AC$ and $BD$.